# python: ValueError: malformed string when loading a dictionary structure

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I am trying to read the following data line by line, each line to a python dictionary format:

test.txt:

```
{u'FirstName': u'John', u'Title': u'Mr', u'LastName': u'Doe', u'LastSeenDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 0, 0)}
{u'FirstName': u'Mary', u'Title': u'Ms', u'LastName': u'Doe', u'LastSeenDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 0, 0)}
```

Here is the code and errors:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        data =ast.literal_eval(line)
        print(data["Title"])
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-d736d3d4199c> in <module>()
     21 
     22 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 23     main()

<ipython-input-27-d736d3d4199c> in main()
     14     with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
     15         for line in ins:
---> 16             data =ast.literal_eval(line)
     17             print(data["Title"])
     18 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     78                 return left - right
     79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
---> 80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 
     82 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in _convert(node)
     61         elif isinstance(node, Dict):
     62             return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
---> 63                         in zip(node.keys, node.values))
     64         elif isinstance(node, Name):
     65             if node.id in _safe_names:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in <genexpr>((k, v))
     60             return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
     61         elif isinstance(node, Dict):
---> 62             return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
     63                         in zip(node.keys, node.values))
     64         elif isinstance(node, Name):

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.pyc in _convert(node)
     77             else:
     78                 return left - right
---> 79         raise ValueError('malformed string')
     80     return _convert(node_or_string)
     81 

ValueError: malformed string
```

---

How do I avoid the malformed string error and what's the proper way to parse these data?

Comment: Where does `test.txt` come from? Seemingly you trust the input, so maybe you can just use pickle?

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 0, 0)` isn't Python literal syntax, and `literal_eval` doesn't handle it.

Comment: @Kay, test.txt is the output of a sql query report. Each line is a report and wrote to a file.

Comment: `literal_eval` is limited in what it will parse (but that's kinda the point) _The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None._ If you control the thing that writes the txt file, have it convert datetime to a string representation.

Comment: This was how I wrote the output: f.write(str(report) + '\n')  where report is the sql response. How do I write it without datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), because it is your data, so you should be able to trust it.

Dump report:

```
from pickle import dump   # cPickle in case of Python2

with open('report.pickle', 'wb') as pickle_stream:
    for row in generate_rows():
        dump(row, pickle_stream, 2)  # The version must be at least 1.
```

Read report:

```
from pickle import load   # cPickle in case of Python2

with open('report.pickle', 'wb') as pickle_stream:
    while True:
        try:
            row = load(pickle_stream)
        except EOFError:
            break

        do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Should generate_a_row be a string? or it needs to be any specific format or structure?

Comment: @Edamame, it can be next to anything¹, that's the nice thing about pickle. A dict, string, list of datetime.datetime … After loading ("unpickling"), the same datatype as you dumped will be returned. So don't convert the input unless it's convenient. (1: Does not work with e.g. open file objects, Sqlalchmy's ResultProxy and similar volatile data.)